# Export database in one file with every dataset existing

Tags: mysql, csv, excel

I've got a unusual question.
The human resources needs to export an old DB to a new one.
And the guys managing the new DB wants one csv file with every dataset existing.
I did a Relational database and now i find it difficult to write the select statement.

I did this:

```
SELECT *
FROM teilnehmer, personen, seminare, termine, kategorien, haeuser
WHERE teilnehmer.sid = seminare.sid  
AND teilnehmer.pid = personen.pid  
AND termine.sid = seminare.sid  
AND seminare.katid = kategorien.katid  
AND personen.hausid = haeuser.hausid
ORDER BY personen.pid
```

but i only get ~1500 entrys.
I know thats to little, because when i look for a Name and all the workshops he/she did, i get much more than what is in this export.

I don't need the answer i would appreciate if someone could give me a little hint in how to get this done.
Till yet i had only like one join for the data i'd needed to display but this confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to specify the type of join.  You really want a "full outer join" which will not exclude records.  A select where you join by keys will default to an inner join.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/259538